# Ubuntu 23.04 - Ubunt Software Center not showing intalled apps under "Installed" tab

Tags: software-center

I'm running a new install of Ubuntu 23.04 and I cannot find any installed apps under the "Installed" tab in the Ubuntu Software Center, not even apps I've installed via the Ubuntu Software app. From what I've read online, it seems that the "Ubuntu Software Center" is actually the "Snap Store", which I've uninstalled and reinstalled without resolving the problem. Is anyone else experiencing the same issue, and if so, has anyone found a solution to the problem? I am able to install apps and uninstall them by searching for the app, but it would obviously be easier if the "Installed" tab showed all the apps.

Comment: I have a vanilla, installed from scratch, instance of v23.04 and selecting Ubuntu Software (the orange briefcase icon) and then `installed` lists all the packages I have installed.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Didn't find any workaround.